# В sql-запросе DELETE не работает OR

Tags: запрос, sqlite3, delete

Требуется удалить из таблицы prop БД sqlite3 все строки, где поле ar = "NULL" ИЛИ поле term = "СУТ".

Я пробую сделать это так:

```
DELETE FROM prop WHERE ar = "NULL" OR term = "СУТ"
```

Но удаляются только строки с ar = "NULL".

Второе условие term = "СУТ" не выполняется. Строки не удаляются.

Подскажите, что неправильно в этом запросе? И как исправить?
Спасибо!

Весь код запроса вот такой:

```
$db->query('DELETE FROM prop WHERE ar = "NULL" OR term = "СУТ"
          AND id > ' . $prev_id, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Не воспроизводится: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJrofhn3ujjWmMBHT7se4a/0#&togetherjs=NN30493uRA

Comment: Дополнила вопрос полным запросом, который не срабатывает. Почему-то удаляются только строки, где ar = "NULL". Строки, где term = "СУТ" не удаляются.

Comment: Ага, это несколько меняет всё, почитайте про приоритеты логических операций.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Булевы операции `AND` и `OR` не равнозначны; `AND` имеет более высокий приоритет, поэтому `X OR Y AND Z` эквивалентно `X OR (Y AND Z)`.

Запомнить это можно так: `AND` — это *логическое умножение*, а `OR` — это *логическое сложение*, соответственно `AND` имеет более высокий приоритет и выполняется раньше.